SwiftUI Singleton ObservableObject with Published var not updating on first display
I have a basic IAP Store that looks like this:
import StoreKit

class Store: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Store()
    
    private var productIDs = ["test.credits", "test.lifetime"] //consumable, non-consumable
    @Published var products = [Product]()
    
    private init() {
        Task {
            await requestProducts()
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func requestProducts() async {
        do {
            products = try await Product.products(for: productIDs)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

In a view, I'm trying to display products like this:
VStack {
    ForEach(Store.shared.products, id: \.id) { product in
        Button(action: {
            Task {
                try await Store.shared.purchase(product)
            }
            
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text(product.displayName)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(product.displayPrice)")
            }
        })
        
    }
}
.task {
    await Store.shared.requestProducts()
}

The first time this screen is shown, no products are displayed. However, the 2nd time and every time after that, the products display fine.
Why aren't they displayed the first time and how can I fix?

Try moving the @MainActor at the top of class declaration. Let me know if it works or not. As I cannot reproduce with ur code.

All ObservableObjects need a property wrapper at every level where you want to see changes. Since you are using a singleton you can use ObservedObject. But know that generally singletons are not considered good practice.

Why do you request product in 2 different places ? Where is define your StateObject ?

The async func you call from .task should return a result that you pass to your model store, e.g. something like this:
@EnvironmentObject var store: Store
@Environment(\.service) var Service

...

.task {
    store.products = await service.fetchProducts()
}

struct Service {
    func fetchProducts() async -> [Product] { // usually this throws
        // do your network request
    }  
}

For button tasks it's like this:
Button(isPurchasing ? "Cancel" : "Purchase") {
    isPurchasing.toggle()
}
.task(id: isPurchasing) {
    if !isPurchasing { return }

    // complete the purchase

    isPurchasing = false
}

